# Path with spaces

Tags: java, path, spaces

I am not a programmer and I need to fix some code to solve a problem.
The problem is that the app does not read file paths with spaces.

**Code:**

```
private void jMenuHELPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //GEN FIRST:event_jMenuHELPActionPerformed
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+" C:\Users\rafi\Documents\Name with spaces\file.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I try to open a file from within the app, it opens a window with the following error:

> ```
> Windows cannot `find C:\Users\rafi\Documents\Name`. Make sure that the name is correct.
> ```

It reads the path only to the first space.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you escape the file argument properly?

Comment: Very honorable for a non-programmer to get your hands dirty and trying to fix code!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the path in quotes. On the command line different parameters are separated by whitespace, and thus the path needs to be surrounded by quotes to indicate it is a single parameter.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:\\Users\\rafi\\Documents\\Name with spaces\\file.txt\"");
```

Comment: Need that plus? I would just pull it out for the answer.

Comment: The double space between start and the path? No, the amount of whitespace is irrelevant.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to escape the ``\`` characters in the `String` too.

Comment: @M.leRutte Actually, I confused plus and space for a second, but removing the extra whitespace is always a good thing in terms of readability (this type of whitespace at least).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `exec` method that takes [an array of arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) instead. Don't forget you also need to escape your backslashes.

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", "C:\\Users\\rafi\\Documents\\Name with spaces\\file.txt"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` characters and [`Desktop.open(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) is how I would use the operating system to open a given file with its' default application for that file type.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\rafi\\Documents\\Name with spaces\\file.txt");
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I did it but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing:

```
private void jMenuHELPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN FIRST:event_jMenuHELPActionPerformed
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+" C:\Users\rafi\Documents\Name\ with\ spaces\file.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That should escape the space character, instead of putting `with` and `spaces\file.txt` as arguments.

Comment: You can either write answers as answers, or suggestions as comments. A suggestion should never be an answer on SO. Wrong answers will earn you downvotes

Comment: @LonelyNeuron oh ok sorry

Comment: I tried this but when I compile it returns error "illegal escape character".

Answer (score 0):

You update your code folowing below:

```
private void jMenuHELPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //GEN FIRST:event_jMenuHELPActionPerformed
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+" C:\\Users\\rafi\\Documents\\Name with spaces\\file.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ...
}
```